# MUCH more Shards needed!

Tags: infamous-second-son

I'm playing InFamous Second Son and started out being 'good', then once I had unlocked all (available at the time) powers, I started doing the 'bad' things to max out its powers. Well.. Lo-And-Behold, I now see money things to unlock under the 'Good' side and I've ended the game and still have yet to max out even all of the 'bad' powers. There seem to be no Shards left anywhere, and all I can do now is just run around doing the D.U.P. Takedown Missions (earning me no Shards), fight Drug Dealers (I subdue them whenever possible) and fight D.U.P. Officers (subduing then whenever possible). I assume I've screwed up horribly and that I'm outta luck, but I need to be sure. Am I forced to start the entire game all over again or can I still upgrade both the 'good' & 'bad' abilities?

Answer (score 1):

There are only enough shards to maximize either the good or bad side.

I believe it is intended that you play the game twice, once as good and once as bad.